# DotNetZip crashes with debugger attached, but works fine otherwise

Tags: c#, debugging, dotnetzip

`DotNetZip` crashes on the following code:

```
        using (ZipFile zipFile = File.Exists(zipFilePath) ? ZipFile.Read(zipFilePath) : new ZipFile(zipFilePath))
        {
            zipFile.UpdateEntry(zipEntryName, content);
            zipFile.Save();
        }
```

with:

```
System.IO.IOException : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.File.InternalMove(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean checkHost)
at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Save()
```

in debug mode with a debugger attached, but it works fine when the debugger is not attached. How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you stop on a Breakpoint somewhere before/in this code?

Comment: I can't remember now :) I think I tried twice, once I stopped on an exception (caught later), and the other time it did break at all.

Comment: OK, maybe you have something in the Watch window that could be executing (undesired) code while your stopping on a Breakpoint.